# mkdir() won't create directories

Tags: php, mkdir

I am trying to create directories for better file organization. The front-end for this is a form where a user will input the title, content and the region(dropdown menu). When the user submit the form, the data will be taken to a file named save.php and will be processed. Below are the codes on the save.php file. Actually the main goal for this is to produce an html file and then organize these html files into folders by region. I cant make the mkdir() to work. The message "directory created" is always printed out but there is no actual folder created. What do you think is the problem on my code? What I want to happen is that when the user  clicks on the "submit" button, folders with region names will be created. Please help? Or any suggestion or another way to solve this problem?

```
$ad_title = $_POST['title'];
$ad_content = $_POST['content-ads']; 
$ad_region = $_POST['region']; 

if (!is_dir("uploads/"$ad_region)) {
        // dir doesn't exist, make it
        mkdir("uploads/".$ad_region);
        echo "directory created!";
    }
    else {
        echo "directory already exist!";
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I dont know if this matters but my **save.php** file and the **uploads folders** where the codes above is saved in the local directory

```
localhost/system/modules/new
```

When I relocated the **save.php** file and the **uploads folder** in the directory

```
localhost/system/
```

all seems to be working now.But I want it to work in the localhost/system/modules/new directory for better organization. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it the absolute path..

You're also missing a dot in is_dir;
Should be `!is_dir("uploads/" . $ad_region`

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path? and yes, the dot is actually in my code, i just forgot to put that here.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a concatenation period in checking if directory exists

`if (!is_dir("uploads/"$ad_region)) {` to `if (!is_dir("uploads/" . $ad_region)) {`

plus add permissions to the `mkdir(path, permission, recursive)` will prevents headaches down the road;

Comment: I already included the period and permission on my code, I just forgot to put that here. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when directories are not created in a web application you are dealing with permission issues.

Make sure the user that is running the web service (if its Linux this is usually 'apache' or 'www-data') is allowed to create directories in the place you are trying to create one.

Comment: Yes, I already checked that and it is allowed to create directories. But still, it wont create.

Comment: If you moved the file (save.php) and the directory (uploads) to an other directory and it "suddenly" worked you are either dealing with a permission issue or the argument(s) to the mk_dir function are incorrect. So it's likely 'user1169875' pointed you in the right direction with the 'absolute path' issue. 
If that is not the case you might want to make sure you don't need the 'recursive' parameter.
To check if you're allowed to write in a directory you can execute the following command 'sudo -u <user that runs the webservice> touch testFile'.